# Checkbox value comes with single value

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

My code is working but there are problem if i choised both of value from form and then only single value added database. Where is going wrong.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'fruit');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' && !isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apple" />APPLE<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value = "Lemon" />LEMON<br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="POST">
</form>';
}elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fruit = $_POST['fruits'];
    foreach ($fruit as $fruits){
        $fruits = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($fruits));
    }
    $sql_add = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO fruit (name) VALUES ('$fruits')");
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 1) {
        echo "Ok not problem.";
    }else {
        echo "There are some problem. Please submit your choice again.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

End the for loop after the insert statement,

```
foreach ($fruit as $fruits){
    $fruits = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($fruits));
    $sql_add = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO fruit (name) VALUES ('$fruits')");
}
```

Comment: SQL request in loop? Are you serious?

Comment: This fixes the issue, but it does cause some overhead. If you check 5 fruits, you will have 5 times the roundtrip to MySQL and 5 times the parsing of the statement. Also this insert is now not atomic. And if you insert a single row at a time like this, and you're already using mysqli, then at least use a prepared statement. But whether this is bad is an opinion. The answer is not wrong.

Comment: @GolezTrol, Please send better alternatives